# Processmaker Installation MySQL Support: undefined , GD Support: not enabled , LDAP Support (*): not enabled

Tags: mysql, gd, processmaker

im having a little problem with my processmaker installation. im tryin to install pocessmaker version 2.5.0.1 using this guide [url]http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/ProcessMaker_Ubuntu_Installation[/url] together with the README.txt file in the processmaker folder. but when i get to the Step 1 of 5: Pre-installation check . i get the following output

Step 1 of 5: Pre-installation check

Pre-installation check
If any of these items is not supported (marked as No) then please take actions to correct them.

Failure to do so could lead to your ProcessMaker installation not functioning correctly!

(*) OpenSSL is optional.
(*) LDAP is optional.

PHP Version >= 5.2.10:  5.3.5-1ubuntu7.11

MySQL Support:  undefined*

cURL Version:  cURL 7.21.3

OpenSSL Version (*):  OpenSSL/0.9.8o

DOM/XML Support:  enabled

GD Support:  not enabled*

Multibyte Strings Support:  enabled

Soap Support:  enabled

LDAP Support (*):  not enabled*

Memory Limit >= 80M:  128M

Notice the MySQL Support , GD Support and LDAP Support (*). i cant move to step 2 until i sort this issue out and i have tried google to get a solution but nothing yet. please i need help . thanks....

Answer (score 1):

The installation wizard says you haven't installed the PHP extensions to MySQL, GD and LDAP.

As the guide you refer to explains, you should have run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5 apache2 php5-mysql php5-gd php5-ldap openssh-server php5-curl php5-cli php5-mcrypt
```

Maybe you have some issue with `php5-mysql`, `php5-gd` and `php5-ldap`, if this is the case try with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql php-gd php-ldap
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved it by:
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin